# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0, reinforcement-learning, tf.keras

With manual DQN code, there is no error seen. But when running via the Keras DQN, it throws the subject line error.

Similar questions have been asked on this forum but they did not help me find answer to my problem. The error is seen when I use Keras DQN library instead of the manual DQN implementation.

My model is as below.

```
    def dqn_model(self):
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(64, input_shape=(1, self.flat_obs,)))  # <== result is (None, 1, 513)
        model.add(Activation('relu'))
```

When I run the below code with Keras DQN :

```
dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, nb_actions=nb_actions, policy=policy, memory=memory,
               nb_steps_warmup=30, gamma=.99, target_model_update=100,
              train_interval=4)
dqn.compile(Adam(learning_rate=.00025), metrics=['mae'])
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=15000, log_interval=1000, visualize=False)
```

Error seen is :

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1)
```

I tried the suggestions as in the question [here-stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60001924/valueerror-error-when-checking-input-expected-dense-input-to-have-shape-46), but it does not help. I am unable to understand what is this shape (1, 1) that DQN complains? And how can I understand and fix this issue?

My questions are:

1. Where does TF pickup the dimension (1, 1). As far as I can understand, I have no where used that shape.
2. In a few suggestions, it asked to reshape the input. Which is what I have already tried and still I get the same error. I am reshaping it to (bacth_size, 1, self.observation_shape.size)

I printed the observation received by the library at timeof failure. It's a dictionary, same as my observation space.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was due to the fact that while the model was built with a flattened dictionary, the DQN was still using the original format dictionary. I was not telling the DQN how to process the dictionary observation space.

So I had to write the below code and just as you would imagine : worked like a charm!

```
class MyProcessor(Processor):
    def process_observation(self, observation):
        print(f"Received data in flatten obs : {len(observation)}")
        flat_observation = []
        for elem in observation['param_2']:
            flat_observation.append(int(elem['prop_1']))
            flat_observation.append(int(elem['prop_2']))
            flat_observation.append(int(elem['prop_3']))
            flat_observation.append(int(elem['prop_4']))
            flat_observation.append(int(elem['prop_5']))
            flat_observation.append(int(elem['prop_6']))
            flat_observation.append(int(elem['prop_7']))
            flat_observation.append(int(elem['prop_8']))
                
        flat_observation.append(observation['param_3'])
        return np.reshape(flat_observation, (-1, np.array(flat_observation).size))
    
    def process_state_batch(self, batch):
        # Transpose the batch of arrays to match the input shape of the network
        try:
            processed_batch = batch.reshape((513, 1)).transpose()
        except:
            processed_batch = np.squeeze(np.concatenate(batch, axis=1))
        print(f"Batch size is : {processed_batch.size}")
        return processed_batch
```